# Is this a brute force attempt? (AWS SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, brute-force

Just had a look through my error logs in SQL Server and i'm seeing the following login attempts multiple times at early hours in the morning (GMT)

2018-10-08 02:54:16.56 Logon Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 58.218.66.218]

2018-10-08 03:12:49.24 Logon Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.

2018-10-08 03:12:49.24 Logon Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 1.188.129.51]

Neither of these IP's are owed by our business. The instance was left open to the open internet, i've now closed this accessible addresses to the bare minimum. Could some one please let me know if this was just a standard brute force attempt?

Edit There are ~300 lines of this in the log with an even split coming from each host.

Thanks,

Connor.

Comment: Brute force usually uses a **much** smaller interval between login attempts than 18 minutes.

Comment: What makes me curious about this is that it comes from different IP's.  If a hacker would try it once and gets the error message that the 'sa' login isn't found? Then why would he/she try it again with a different IP? Could be scanners that look everywhere for possible targets.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't brute force. Rather, if these are unknown IPs, it most likely a scanner that is checking for DB instances and checking access on Microsoft-shipped accounts.

Since SA is enabled by default and in the SysAdmin server role, if a DBA/company is foolish enough to expose their instance to the internet, leave the role enabled, and have a very weak password, some lucky hacker can have a field day with your database if they attempt to authenticate with sa and guess your password (ie you set it as 'admin').

Best practices are to set the SA account with an absurdly long password, disable the account, and set your instance to only allow Windows Authentication, not mixed.