# AWS RDS (SQL Server) suspicious brute force login attempts

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-rds

I have created a public RDS (SQL Server) instance. For my project requirement it has to be public. When I checked the log it shows several thousands of entries of failed login attempt from some IPs like the following, (i've tried creating several instances in different zones but still same issues). Any kind of help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Error Log:

```
2020-02-03 09:45:28.98 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 61.12.74.190]
2020-02-03 09:45:29.31 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2020-02-03 09:45:29.31 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 61.12.74.190]
2020-02-03 09:45:29.42 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2020-02-03 09:45:29.42 Logon       Login failed for user 'mssqla'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 112.53.236.114]
2020-02-03 09:45:29.48 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2020-02-03 09:45:29.48 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 61.12.74.190]
2020-02-03 09:45:29.73 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2020-02-03 09:45:29.73 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 61.12.74.190]
2020-02-03 09:45:30.08 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2020-02-03 09:45:30.08 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 61.12.74.190]
```

As a temporary fix i have black listed all the ip from VPC -> Network ACLs, for a couple of IPs this solution is OK but for hundreds of IPs this solution is quite painful so **I'm expecting a much more efficient way to resolve this issue**.

**NOTE:**

I checked the AWS forum and found a very old and similar issue but NO answer there https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=196538&#196538

Also, found a similar question on stackoverflow [Is this a brute force attempt? (AWS SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704603/is-this-a-brute-force-attempt-aws-sql-server) which is also does NOT have any specified solution.

Comment: That's what life is like on the Internet. There are an incredible number of bots trying standard methods of breaking into computers, databases, routers, etc. Take a look at the logs in your home router and you'll see how many continuous attempts are being made for all types of vulnerabilities. Perhaps you can figure out a way to remove it from being publicly accessible, yet still provide access for your particular use-case.

Comment: Since most of the IPs are chinese, Is there any way to block certain country from VPC?

Comment: Did you look at AWS WAF...

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee Good thinking, but unfortunately AWS WAF works for web requests (_Web Application Firewall_) and can only be associated with Amazon CloudFront or an Elastic Load Balancer.

Answer (score 2):

change the default sql server port 1433 by other...

PD: exactly the same problem was happening to me, I looked for aws information and its solution became very complicated, so I thought that if it is a brute force attack it would be the default sql user, sa, and the default port 1433, then change the default port and the connection of my application and solved the problem ... complex problem, simple solution.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide additional detail on why you think this will resolve the issue, or is a recommended practice for public facing SQL servers? I'd imagine that any competent exploit could easily scan any publicly exposed ports, instead of assuming that SQL will always be exposed via the default 1433 port.

Comment: Whenever you mount a bd in an RDS and leave the default port this type of attack happens, in my opinion it is random, start testing again and again with the user sa and a password, detect it because the error log started to grow , step from kb to hundreds of megabytes and the database began to slow down

Comment: This is the solution! Also change port for [Remote Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/change-listening-port).

Comment: @JeremyCaney You're not special, your server is not special! Scans are done on large scale and only default ports are used. If someone scans the ports on your server specifically to locate your SQL port... you've got way bigger problems and I don't think SO is the solution.